# When designing HTML templates for emails, what should i know

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

When implementing an HTML template that will be sent in an email, what should I know? For example, I know most email clients do not download images by default. How do you get around that? What are other css/html implementations that are not supported?

Comment: Yikes... That's a lot to answer.  SO is intended for programing questions addressing one specific problem at a time.  There's no objective answer to this question, but if you're just looking for a springboard to start researching this on your own, I'd suggest looking at the resources information at https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/.  They have a lot of good information and a fantastic list of what CSS you can use and where: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing as a rule of thumb is: When you code HTML emails, code like you're back in the 90s. That is: Table layouts!

Wrap everything in a Table widh

```
border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
```

CSS is supported in some mail clients, others fitler it completely. Some clients only allow inline-styles, not style tags. So it's best to still use `<font>` tags for text styling and the deprecated `bgcolor` attribute, and so on. Padding/margin around elements should not be generated using CSS `padding` and `margin`, but rather by using empty table cells that include a transparent 1x1px gif. Make sure to apply the height to the `img` tag as well as the `td` and if you really want to make sure, also the `tr` tag.

Things are getting better and better, with Gmail recently making changes that allow media queries for responsiveness, but that has not rolled out globally yet.

So with media queries not (yet) working everywhere and most people using mobile devices nowadays, it's not a bad idea to use a "mobile-first" approach and use media queries on larger displays to extend the layout. For Outlook, you can use conditional comments (as it doesn't support media queries either) to achieve the same:

```
<!--[if mso]>
<style>/* style block will only be used in MSO */</style>
<![endif]-->
```

where you are also able to target specific Outlook versions, for example the current Windows 10 Mail app is `mso 16`. You can use `lte/gte/gt/lt` just like in conditional comments used for old IEs in earlier times.

Speaking of Outlook: It's also a pain in the ... eye in some other areas. To force line-height and prevent some unwanted spaces, there are MSO-specific styles like `mso-line-height-alt:0;` and `mso-margin-top-alt:1px;`, I recommend reading up on these as well.

For column layouts, do not use float, but `align="left"` on each table that represents a column, except for the last table in a "row" (because that will cause problems with tables floating off the grid in Thunderbird).

In my experience, at least if you're starting a template from scratch, it's a matter of building, testing in clients (webmail, desktop and mobile devices), fixing, doing research about some client-specific things that don't look the way you'd like them, trying out some own attempts to fix it, and testing all over again.

Answer (score 2):

Email clients and rendering engines
Email clients use different rendering engines to render HTML emails:

Apple Mail, Outlook for Mac, Android Mail and iOS Mail use WebKit

Outlook 2000/02/03 use Internet Explorer

Outlook 2007/10/13 use Microsoft Word (yes, Word!)

Web clients use their browser’s respective engine e.g. Safari uses WebKit, Chrome uses Blink

Update November 2016: Just [recently](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/09/your-emails-optimized-for-every-screen-with-responsive-design.html) Google announced support for embedded CSS and media queries in Gmail. This is HUGE for the email development industry. Now, as of September 2016, Gmail will support a slew of [CSS](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/reference/supported_css) properties which makes template development a lot easier for Gmail.

Litmus has a handy website dedicated to the current [email client market share](http://emailclientmarketshare.com/), based on their own internal stats (~1 billion emails).

font: http://www.leemunroe.com/building-html-email/

I suggest to you use and test these ones:

https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus

http://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html

http://litmus.com/

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't link any external stylesheet, You cant use floats, some clients ignore background images. Your should check out [foundation for email](https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/email-templates.html) if you wish to use good looking html emails in your projects that most clients support. There are several default templates available that you can use or you can build your own custom designs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot you need to know, but a few big ones that comes to mind are:

- Use table based layout
- Use HTML4 syntax
- Use CSS2 syntax
- Use inline css (`style=`) and do not include a `style` tag in the `head`
- Use `alt` text for all images and use a background color as a fallback when the image hasn't been downloaded yet.

Those are just a few pointers, but I agree @Joseph Marikle, refer to the link he posted.